# Converting $\neg(A\land B)\land(B\lor\neg C)\Leftrightarrow(\neg A\land B)\lor(\neg B\land\neg C)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, binary-operations

$$\neg(A\land B)\land(B\lor\neg C)\Leftrightarrow(\neg A\land B)\lor(\neg B\land\neg C)$$
Checked their truth tables are the same, but can you show the steps how to transform one to the other?

Comment: Thanks. Its <->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\overline{AB} (B \vee \bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow (\bar{A} \vee \bar{B})(B \vee \bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow \bar{A}B \vee \bar{A} \bar{C} \vee \bar{B} B \vee \bar{B} \bar{C} \Leftrightarrow \bar{A}B \vee \bar{A} \bar{C} \vee \bar{B} \bar{C}$$
Now if $\bar{A} \bar{C}$ turns out to be true, either $\bar{A} B$ or $\bar{B} \bar{C}$ must be true, because $B$ is either true or false. That's why you can leave $\bar{A} \bar{C}$ out and you get your result:
$$ \overline{AB} (B \vee \bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow \bar{A} B \vee \bar{B} \bar{C}$$

You can also use some boolean algebra to eliminate $\bar{A} \bar{C}$:

$$ \bar{A}B \vee \bar{A} \bar{C} \vee \bar{B} \bar{C} \Leftrightarrow \bar{A}B \vee \bar{A} \bar{C} (B \vee \bar{B}) \vee \bar{B} \bar{C} \Leftrightarrow \bar{A} B \vee \bar{A} \bar{C} B \vee \bar{A} \bar{C} \bar{B} \vee \bar{B}\bar{C} \\ \Leftrightarrow \bar{A} B (1 \vee \bar{C}) \vee \bar{B} \bar{C}(\bar{A} \vee 1) \Leftrightarrow \bar{A} B \vee \bar{B} \bar{C}$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I can understand the expansions. Just that the "getting rid of ~A && ~C" part is stuck. Could you use formula instead of reasoning to explain how you got rid of that?

Comment: Sure, added it to the answer above.

Comment: Wow thanks! What is this technique called? To add `&& (X || !X)` to eliminate some redundant item?

Comment: Actually i don't know if it has a name, it's really usefull though for stuff like this.Techniques like this are also used in Shannon's expansion theorem, which is used to transform any boolean expression into it's normal form, if you're interested in that.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @Koepi's Answer:

To go from $(\neg A \land B) \lor (\neg A \land \neg C) \lor (\neg B \land \neg C)$ to $(\neg A \land B) \lor (\neg B \land \neg C)$ is an immediate application of the Consensus theorem:

**Consensus**

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land R) = (P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R)$$

Proof:

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land R) = \text{ (Adjacency)} $$

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land Q \land R) \lor (P \land \neg Q \land R) = \text{ (Absorption)} $$

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R)$$

And if you are unfamiliar with Adjacency and Absorption:

**Adjacency**

$$P = (P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q)$$

Proof:

$$P = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$P \land \top = \text{ (Complement)}$$

$$P \land (Q \lor \neg Q) = \text{ (Distribuition)}$$

$$(P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q)$$

**Absorption**

$$P \lor (P \land Q) = P$$

Proof:

$$P \lor (P \land Q) = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$(P \land \top) \lor (P \land Q) = \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$P \land (\top \lor Q) = \text{ (Annihilation)}$$

$$P \land \top = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$P$$

Comment: Great stuff! What a speedy way to reach the result, only if the pattern can be easily recognisable.

Comment: @user1589188 Yeah, these are pretty powerful and useful principles. You should put them into your 'boolean algebra toolbox' immediately! :)